# Echo month name from numeric value

Tags: php, html, get

I am tring to show a month name dependant on a numeric value. So if 11, show November, if 9 show September and so on.

Here is my code:

```
 $month=$_GET["q"];             


if($month['month'] == '11')
{
  echo"November";
}

if($month['month'] == '10')
{
  echo"October";
}

     if($month['month'] == '9')
{
  echo"September";
}
```

This doesn't show anything? Can anyone help?

Comment: So what does `$_GET["q"]` show if you var_dump() it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to create multiple `if` statements. You can simply use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to achieve this:

```
$month_number = (int) $_GET["q"]; 
if($month_number > 0 && $month_number <= 12)
    echo DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $month_number)->format('F');
```

Answer (score 2):

If `$_GET['q']` has your month number, you need to use only `$month` and not `$month['month']`.

Probably, this is best way to achieve your result using Non-OOP PHP:

```
$month = $_GET['q'];
$monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month));
echo $monthName;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will like this

```
if($month == '11') {

}
```

Because you are directly assigning the `GET` value to `$month`.Assuemed that `q` will be the month name.

Answer (score 0):

because $_GET["q"] can't be an array, so you can't use $month['month'], use $month directly

and instead of so many if else you can use, the following code to echo month name directly.

```
$monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month));
echo $monthName;
```

More details at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: what will be the `10` at your mktime..??

Comment: corrected it, it represented no of days, so it should not have been here.

Answer (score 0):

here in your case **$month** is variable not a array so try to use like this...

```
    if($month=='11')
        echo 'Nov';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
$monthArr = array('1'=>'Jan','2'=>'Feb');
echo $monthArr[$month];
```

Answer (score 0):

$month = date('n');

```
 if($month == '11') 
    {
      echo "November";
    }
    if($month == '10')
     {
      echo "November";
    }
```

make sure you get the correct value eg:10,11... for month variable

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use string to time.

```
$month=$_GET["q"]; 
echo date('F', strtotime('2012-' . $month . '-01'));
```

This will give you the full name of the month dependent of what number the month variable is assigned.

Strtotime requires the date, hence why 2012 etc is in there also, albeit irrelevant to the output.